# pandas - take last N rows from one subgroup

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's suppose we have a dataframe that be generated using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'p1': np.random.rand(32),
     'a1': np.random.rand(32),
     'phase': [0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3, 0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3],
     'file_number': [1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 2,2,2,2, 2,2,2,2, 2,2,2,2]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

For each file number i want to take only last N rows of phase number 3. So that the result for N==2 looks like this:

[image]

Currently I'm doing it in this way:

```
def phase_3_last_n_observations(df, n):
    result = []
    for fn in df['file_number'].unique():
        file_df = df[df['file_number']==fn]
        for phase in [0,1,2,3]:
            phase_df = file_df[file_df['phase']==phase]
            if phase == 3:
                phase_df = phase_df[-n:]

            result.append(phase_df)
    df = pd.concat(result, axis=0)
    return df 

phase_3_last_n_observations(df, 2)
```

However, it is very slow and I have terabytes of data, so I need to worry about performance. Does anyone have any idea how to speed my solution up? Thanks!

Comment: kindly add `np.random.seed(123)` to make it reproducible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use idea from deleted answer - get indices by previous rows for rows matching `3` by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and remove them by [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
def phase_3_last_n_observations(df, N):

    df1 = df[df['phase'].eq(3)]
    idx = df1[df1.groupby('file_number').cumcount(ascending=False).ge(N)].index
    return df.drop(idx)

#index is reseted for default, because used for remove rows
df = phase_3_last_n_observations(df.reset_index(drop=True), 2)
```

Comment: Very nice and fast solution! It was around 100 times faster in my tests. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Filter the rows where phase is `3` then groupby and use `tail` to select the last two rows per `file_number`, finally `append` to get the result

```
m = df['phase'].eq(3)
df[~m].append(df[m].groupby('file_number').tail(2)).sort_index()
```

---

```
          p1        a1  phase  file_number
0   0.223906  0.164288      0            1
1   0.214081  0.748598      0            1
2   0.567702  0.226143      0            1
3   0.695458  0.567288      0            1
4   0.760710  0.127880      1            1
5   0.592913  0.397473      1            1
6   0.721191  0.572320      1            1
7   0.047981  0.153484      1            1
8   0.598202  0.203754      2            1
9   0.296797  0.614071      2            1
10  0.961616  0.105837      2            1
11  0.237614  0.640263      2            1
14  0.500415  0.220355      3            1
15  0.968630  0.351404      3            1
16  0.065283  0.595144      0            2
17  0.308802  0.164214      0            2
18  0.668811  0.826478      0            2
19  0.888497  0.186267      0            2
20  0.199129  0.241900      1            2
21  0.345185  0.220940      1            2
22  0.389895  0.761068      1            2
23  0.343100  0.582458      1            2
24  0.182792  0.245551      2            2
25  0.503181  0.894517      2            2
26  0.144294  0.351350      2            2
27  0.157116  0.847499      2            2
30  0.194274  0.143037      3            2
31  0.542183  0.060485      3            2
```

Answer (score 0):

**As an alternative solution to what already exists:** You can calculate the last elements for all phase groups and afterwards just use `.loc` to get the needed group result. I have written the code for `N==2`, if you want for `N==3`, then use `[-1, -2, -3]`

```py
result = df.groupby(['phase']).nth([-1, -2])

PHASE = 3
result.loc[PHASE]
```